# The state does not change in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the state based on the error request. Initially I set it to false, upon error I update it to true. but I always see it to be false. Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Below is the code snippet,

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: false,
        };
    }
    submit = () => {
        function_1.finally(() => {
          ............
        }).catch((request) => {
            const errors = request.response.errors;
            let err1;
            if (errors) {
                err1 = errors.find(
                    e => e.code === 'error_code');
            }
            if (err1) {
               this.setState({
                        error: true,
                    });
            }  else {
                this.setState({error: false});
            }

        });
    };
    };
    render = () => {
        const { error } = this.state;
        console.log("error in render", error); //this is always false
    };
}
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about the error response, it just looks to me like your conditions aren't evaluating to true at any point, thus never setting `error` to `True`. Can you possibly share a bit more context?

Comment: What if it is never executing if block. Your state seems to be updating there.

Comment: can you please show the content of `function_1` ?

Comment: @shubam Gupta: the log statement in if(err1) block executes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catch block accepts the `error` parameter instead of accessing through `request.response.errors`, try like this:

```
.catch((error) => {
   const errorStatus = Boolean(error.find(e => e.code === 'error_code'))
   this.setState({
    error: errorStatus
   })
})
```

But I suppose, catch block is run only after the error is caught, so why not simply set error state to true instead of checking error_code?

```
.catch(() => {
   this.setState({
    error: true
   })
})
```